# Implement script in my WebView

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have this WebView and I want to open this script in it. How do I do this?

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
   webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:<script>http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=xxxxxxxxx</script>")
```

Here is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=xxxxxxxx"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, I haven't tested it so might have minor errors. But it should give you the idea:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {  
  @Override  
  public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { " +  
    "var script=document.createElement('script');" +
    "script.type='text/javascript';" + 
    "script.src='http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=xxxxxxxx';" +
    "document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0).appendChild(script);"+  
    "})");  
  }  
});  
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have found a correct answer myself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
 WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    webview.bringToFront();
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    String html = "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ad.leadboltads.net/show_app_ad.js?section_id=xxxxxxxx'></script>";
    webview.loadData(html, "text/html", "utf-8");
```